# NSURLSessionDataTask does not return data from request

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to make a request to a server, which should return data that I can use in the rest of my application. Here is my code:

```
func makeNewUser() -> NSDictionary {
    var full_url = getFullUrl("makeNewUser")
    var toReturn: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:full_url)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        println(response)
        var err: NSError?

        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        toReturn = jsonResult
    });
    task.resume()
    self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(toReturn)
    println(toReturn)
    return toReturn
}
```

I am sending toReturn data to a delegate function in the caller, but it is not available. I believe the reason for this is because the request is asynchronous. What is the proper way for me to handle this so that the caller knows to wait for this data before continuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the delegate call into the session completion block:

```
func makeNewUser() {
    var full_url = getFullUrl("makeNewUser")
    var toReturn: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:full_url)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        println(response)
        var err: NSError?

        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonResult)   // <<-----
    });
    task.resume()
}
```

And you just have to be aware that the result is not immediately available.  You don't want to block the function (and UI) on long running operations like network requests anyway.